# how to join tables by condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume that I have 2 tables that I want to join them. but I need to decide INNER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN according to a parameter.

is there any way achieve this?

Comment: only with dynamic sql

Comment: Use a `left join` and handle the conditions in the  `where` clause

Comment: @Y.S if you mean string concatenation it is not an option.

Comment: @ypbr: Since you asked a vague question, you will get only vague answers. If you add example data and expected output to your question then you might get an answer that really helps you.

Comment: @juergend I know but I haven't started to code yet. I have just need someone to give me some hint to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, not sure about the performance - I imagine it is ok:

```
DECLARE @join char(1) = 'L' -- L(eft),R(ight),I(nner)

DECLARE @t1 table(id int)
DECLARE @t2 table(id int)
INSERT @t1 values(1),(2)
INSERT @t2 values(2),(3)

SELECT t1.id t1id, t2.id t2id 
FROM
  @t1 t1
FULL JOIN
  @t2 t2
ON
  t1.id = t2.id
WHERE 
  @join = 'L' and t1.id is not null
  or @join = 'R' and t2.id is not null
  or @join = 'I' and t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare a variable and use the variable in the `JOIN` condition. You can put `UNION ALL` so that when one of the result set gives result set, you will get the needed result set.

```
DECLARE @isLEFTJOIN bit = 0
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b
ON a.Id = b.Id
WHERE @isLEFTJOIN = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS a
JOIN Table2 AS b
ON a.Id = b.Id
WHERE @isLEFTJOIN = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an `IF` statement:

```
DECLARE @jointype char(1) = 'L' --(L)EFT JOIN, (R)IGHT JOIN, (I)NNER JOIN

IF @jointype = 'L'    
 Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.condition = Table2.condition

IF @jointype = 'R'
 Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.condition = Table2.condition

IF @jointype = 'I'
 Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.condition = Table2.condition
```